# What causes a method wrapped via a metaclass to forget self when called?

Tags: python, metaclass

The following code allows me to follow the operation of how metaclasses work. However, when 
lines 21 and 22 are uncommented, `Metaclass.__init__` will fail because the `self` argument is not passed to the wrapped method. What is causing `VerboseFunction.__call__` to not pass the needed `Metaclass` instance to the initializer?

```
import sys, types

def sign(prefix, argcount=None):
    f = sys._getframe(1)
    print('{}.{}({})\n'.format(prefix, f.f_code.co_name,
        ', '.join(repr(f.f_locals[name])
        for name in f.f_code.co_varnames[:f.f_code.co_argcount
        if argcount is None else min(argcount, f.f_code.co_argcount)])))

class VerboseMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        sign('VerboseMetaclass')
        for key in sorted(classdict):
            classdict[key.encode()] = value = classdict.pop(key)
            classdict[key] = cls.wrap('{}.{}'.format(name, key), value)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)

    def wrap(key, value):
        sign('VerboseMetaclass')
##        if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
##            return VerboseFunction(key, value)
        return value

class VerboseFunction:

    def __init__(self, name, func):
        vars(self).update(locals())

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.name.endswith('.__init__'):
            print('SPECIAL !!!')
        name = self.call(args, kwargs)
        print('[ -> ] {!s}\n'.format(name))
        try:
            value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
            print('[ <- ] {!s} [return {!r}]\n'.format(name, value))
            return value
        except:
            value = sys.exc_info()[1]
            print('[ <- ] {!s} [raise {!r}]\n'.format(name, value))
            raise

    def call(self, args, kwargs):
        args = tuple('{!r}'.format(item) for item in args)
        kwargs = tuple('{!s}={!r}'.format(key, kwargs[key])
                       for key in sorted(kwargs))
        return '{}({})'.format(self.name, ', '.join(args + kwargs))

class Metaclass(type, metaclass=VerboseMetaclass):

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases):
        sign('Metaclass')
        return super().__prepare__(name, bases)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        sign('Metaclass')
        for key, value in {'__new__': cls.new, '__init__': cls.init}.items():
            if key in classdict:
                classdict[key.encode()] = classdict[key]
                classdict[key] = value
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)

    def __init__(self, name, bases, classdict):
        sign('Metaclass')
        return super().__init__(name, bases, classdict)

    def __call__(self):
        sign('Metaclass')
        return super().__call__()

    def new(cls):
        sign('Metaclass')
        return vars(cls)[b'__new__'](cls)

    def init(self):
        sign('Metaclass')
        return vars(self.__class__)[b'__init__'](self)

class Test(metaclass=Metaclass):

    def __new__(cls):
        sign('Test')
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        sign('Test')
        return super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        sign('Test')

Test().run()
```

Comment: FWIW, running with Python 3.3 alpha, I get `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'classdict'`. Edit: which means nothing new :/

Comment: VerboseMetaclass.wrap signature should not be wrap(self, key, value) or be decorated by @classmethod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VerboseMetaclass` class can be modified, and the `VerboseFunction` class can be removed. `VerboseMetaclass.wrap` should be altered as follows, and `wrap_function` should be added.

```
@classmethod
def wrap(cls, key, value):
    sign('VerboseMetaclass')
    if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
        return cls.wrap_function(key, value)
    return value

def wrap_function(name, func):
    sign('VerboseMetaclass')
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def verbose_function(*args, **kwargs):
        args_str = tuple(repr(item) for item in args)
        kwargs_str = tuple('{!s}={!r}'.format(*pair)
                           for pair in sorted(kwargs.items()))
        signature = '{}({})'.format(name, ', '.join(args_str + kwargs_str))
        print('[ -> ] {}\n'.format(signature))
        try:
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print('[ <- ] {!s} [return {!r}]\n'.format(signature, value))
            return value
        except:
            value = sys.exc_info()[1]
            print('[ <- ] {!s} [raise {!r}]\n'.format(signature, value))
            raise
    return verbose_function
```

---

**Edit:** The finished second draft of this code can be seen below. The purpose of this example is to observe the "machinery" involved in creating, instantiating, and monitoring classes and their instances. Much of the code is also self-monitoring (except for the `VerboseMetaclass`), so it is possible to see how the code itself is operating. By setting the metaclass of your class to `Metaclass`, your own classes and their instances will print out monitoring messages as well. The `Test` class provides an example.

```
import types, functools, sys

class VerboseMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        for key in sorted(filter(
            lambda name: isinstance(name, str), classdict)):
            classdict[key] = cls.wrap('{}.{}'.format(name, key), classdict[key])
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)

    @classmethod
    def wrap(cls, name, value):
        if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
            return cls.wrap_function(name, value)
        if isinstance(value, classmethod):
            return classmethod(cls.wrap_function(name, value.__func__))
        if isinstance(value, staticmethod):
            return staticmethod(cls.wrap_function(name, value.__func__))
        try:
            return VerboseData(name, value)
        except NameError:
            return value

    def wrap_function(name, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def verbose_function(*args, **kwargs):
            args_str = tuple((object.__repr__(item)
                              if isinstance(item, VerboseData)
                              else repr(item)) for item in args)
            kwargs_str = tuple('{!s}={!r}'.format(*pair)
                               for pair in sorted(kwargs.items()))
            signature = '{}({})'.format(name, ', '.join(args_str + kwargs_str))
            print('[ -> ] {}\n'.format(signature))
            try:
                value = func(*args, **kwargs)
                print('[ <- ] {!s} [return {!r}]\n'.format(signature, value))
                return value
            except:
                value = sys.exc_info()[1]
                print('[ <- ] {!s} [raise {!r}]\n'.format(signature, value))
                raise
        return verbose_function

class VerboseData(metaclass=VerboseMetaclass):

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        vars(self).update(locals())

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        value = self.value
        if isinstance(value, (property, VerboseData)):
            value = value.__get__(instance, owner)
        print('[ get ] {!s} = {!r}\n'.format(self.name, value))
        return value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('[ set ] {!s} = {!r}\n'.format(self.name, value))
        if isinstance(self.value, (property, VerboseData)):
            self.value.__set__(instance, value)
        else:
            self.value = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        print('[ XX ] {}\n'.format(self.name))
        if isinstance(self.value, (property, VerboseData)):
            self.value.__delete__(instance)
        else:
            del self.value

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.value)

class Metaclass(VerboseMetaclass, metaclass=VerboseMetaclass):

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases):
        return super().__prepare__(name, bases)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        for key, value in {'__new__': cls.new, '__init__': cls.init}.items():
            if key in classdict:
                classdict[key.encode()] = classdict[key]
                classdict[key] = value
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)

    def __init__(self, name, bases, classdict):
        return super().__init__(name, bases, classdict)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for base in cls.__mro__:
            try:
                return vars(base)[b'__new__'](cls, *args, **kwargs)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for base in self.__class__.__mro__:
            try:
                return vars(base)[b'__init__'](self, *args, **kwargs)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return object.__init__(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Test(metaclass=Metaclass):

        def __new__(cls):
            return super().__new__(cls)

        def __init__(self):
            return super().__init__()

        def run(self):
            pass

    Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just getting lost in a maze of your own design, either that or I am :)

Your error can be modelled as:

```
class VerboseFunction:

    def __init__(self, name, func):
        self.name, self.func = name, func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

class Metaclass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # Comment out the line below
    __init__ = VerboseFunction('Metaclass.__init__', __init__)

print(Metaclass())
```

Which means you're calling `Metaclass.__init__()` directly without having an instance as self.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the problem! A little research provided a solution that was somewhat more complete. Your answer gave me the idea to use a wrapper instead of the VerboseFunction class.